# 2Checkout & Wishlist Member plugin wordpress integration not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, integration, member, 2checkout

I am having problems integrating 2checkout with wishlist member plugin in wordpress. I have followed all the steps in this [integration video](http://member.wishlistproducts.com/2checkout-integration/) provided by the guys at wishlist but I cannot seem to get the registration once filled out to forward to the shopping cart for payment.

I feel like I am either missing something or I have made a mistake at some point.

This is the registration url that I am using, please feel free to sign up to it and test it out. You will notice it isn't forwarding to the 2checkout site for payment (Is this even meant to happen at this stage?).

http://mutestserver.com/index.php?/register/Fdins7

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You must add 2checkout buy buttons to your site in order for registrarion to work.

The URL you have given here is the **private** registration link. It bypasses everything.

The corect order should be like this:

JOIN NOW PAGE->2checkout button->shop page->activation :)

Go to: http://businessidea4u.com Different SC and PG, but same logic :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured this out on my own about 3 hours after I posted on here :(.

Answer (score 0):

The process of integrate Wishlist Member with any payment gateway is different.

When a visitor wants to buy you product he moves through this steps:

1. Clicking the buy button
2. He will be transferred to payment gateway in your case 2Checkout
3. After the payment have been completed he will get registration form.

What you need to do is:

Add a buy button (this one is supplied to you by 2checkout) 
You will need to fill all the right information in 2Checkout to get the button to work.

The URL that you put in the 2Checkout setting is not the registration form URL it's a special URL that you will find on the integrating page on your specific website.

You will be able to find the exact steps for your website under:

Integration -->  Shopping Cart ---->  select the 2Checkout payment

You can see how the process is working with Clickbank on:

http://WishlistRegistrationWidget.com

the user first click the buy button then he is transferred to the payment page and the payment page he getting back to the registration form.